# Parse.com Android Images not showing on actual device. Shows on emulator

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am making an app in Android Studio using Parse SDK. When I run the device on the emulator, its works fine. On the actual device, it will not show the images. Here's is the code:

```
public class ImageLoader {

MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
        .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService;
// Handler to display images in UI thread
Handler handler = new Handler();

public ImageLoader(Context context) {
    fileCache = new FileCache(context);
    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

final int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
    if (bitmap != null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
   final File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if (b != null)
        return b;

    // Download Images from the Internet
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        conn.disconnect();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
            memoryCache.clear();
        return null;
    }
}

// Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
        stream1.close();

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
        stream2.close();
        return bitmap;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

// Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad {
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
        url = u;
        imageView = i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            handler.post(bd);
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
    String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

// Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
        bitmap = b;
        photoToLoad = p;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if (bitmap != null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}
```

There is also a exception that will show a clue to what's going on.
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/AggiesLand/878582989: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

IS there any way to show the images on the actual device?

Edit: Here is the logcat

> 06-26 17:52:56.778  21588-22075/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/AggiesLand/878582989: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>   06-26 17:52:56.778  21588-22075/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
>   06-26 17:52:56.778  21588-22075/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:88)
>   06-26 17:52:56.778  21588-22075/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:73)
>   06-26 17:52:56.778  21588-22075/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ at com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:78)
>   06-26 17:52:56.778  21588-22075/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ at com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app.ImageLoader.access$000(ImageLoader.java:28)
>   06-26 17:52:56.778  21588-22075/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ at com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:152)
>   06-26 17:52:56.778  21588-22075/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
>   06-26 17:52:56.778  21588-22075/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   06-26 17:52:56.778  21588-22075/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   06-26 17:52:56.778  21588-22075/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   06-26 17:52:56.778  21588-22075/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>   06-26 17:52:56.788  21588-22075/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>   06-26 17:52:56.788  21588-22079/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/AggiesLand/-1260189210: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>   06-26 17:52:56.788  21588-22079/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
>   06-26 17:52:56.788  21588-22079/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:88)
>   06-26 17:52:56.788  21588-22075/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ at     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
>   06-26 17:52:56.788  21588-22079/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:73)
>   06-26 17:52:56.788  21588-22075/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
>   06-26 17:52:56.788  21588-22075/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
>   06-26 17:52:56.788  21588-22075/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ ... 10 more
>   06-26 17:52:56.788  21588-22079/com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app W/System.err﹕ com.lbbw.AggiesLand.aggiesland.app.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:78)

Comment: Is it not obvious? The file you are looking for does not exist. Please post the logcat

Comment: I already posted the logcat